# How do I debug a Thread 1: signabrt, debug console doesn't show any logs

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native-firebase

My ios project builds and installs on the device but has a runtime crash after launcher screen finishes.

I'm looking in the debugger console but I don't see any logs to help me diagnose what is going on.  My project was working correctly before I upgraded react-native-firebase from v3 to v4 https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/releases.  Stepping into or over the code doesn't show me any errors in the code itself.

[image]

I'm hesitant to log an issue with the react-native-firebase project before I understand what the error could be - and whether it was a simple error somewhere.

However, the error seems pretty cryptic and I don't have any clues on what's actually causing the runtime crash.  Is there a way that I can read more verbose logs that might give more info on the crash?

Answer (score 0):

**add an Exception breakpoint**: by going to the breakpoint tab (command + 8) and the click the add "+" button on the bottom left corner and click on Exception breakpoint - all exceptions.

That will pause the code exactly were the exception is being raced therefore you will be able to see the line of code that it is causing the crash.

Comment: that shows an exception at `RCTNativeModule::invokeInner` but I can't seem to read the caught exception at that breakpoint.  I tried reverting my javascript to a hello world simple example but it still crashes.

Comment: You need to provide more details @MonkeyBonkey. I can't find that RCTNativeModule on the RNFirebase framework

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't any more logger output to share - that's the challenge I'm facing in trying to debug without any more information.